# Why do I get this MinGW error after building several times, Permission denied

Tags: mingw

After building my program every 5 or so times I get this error, it's not fatal because simply running `make` again usually compiles the program and all is fine but I don't know why this error is shown, what causes it?

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: reopening
program.exe: Permission denied

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: 
Permission denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [skbx2] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means the process `program.exe` is still running. You can check task manager to find and kill it before rebuilding. The fact that it is running is either because you have a debugger attached or the program is not exiting cleanly and Windows is dumping some error information, or the program just keeps running.

Comment: ah. that actually makes alot of sense, i'm coding an opengl app and sometimes to quickly test it i skip deleting the resources allocated. thanks.